# Cross-platform (linux/Win32) nonblocking C++ IO on stdin/stdout/stderr

Tags: c++, pipe, stdin, iostream, nonblocking

I'm trying to find the best solution for nonblocking IO via stdin/stdout with the following characteristics:

- As long as there is enough data, read in *n*-sized chunks.
- If there's not enough data, read in a partial chunk.
- If there is no data available, block until there is some (even though it may be smaller than *n*).

The goal is to allow efficient transfer for large datasets while processing 'control' codes immediately (instead of having them linger in some partially-filled buffer somewhere).

I know I can achieve this by using threads and a istream::get() loop, or by writing a bunch of platform-specific code (since you can't select() on file handles in windows)... ((There is also istream::readsome() which seems promising, but the only results I can find on google were of people saying it doesn't actually work well.))

Since I haven't done much coding w/ these APIs, perhaps there is a better way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) can be of use for you?

Comment: That looks rather promising (a big hammer for a small problem, but probably worth learning)... Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that's probably your best bet for portable asynchronous I/O, since the language doesn't have native support for nonblocking I/O *or* threads. You'll have to use a library of some kind, and boost is usually a good bet.

Comment: (If only Win32 supported select() or poll() on arbitrary handles instead of just sockets)... 

After doing some digging, I've confirmed that I can do what I need and there's even a tutorial for setting it up: http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/process/tutorials.html#process.tutorials.async_io

Comment: Addendum: The tutorial is for snagging the stdin/stdout of a child process using async streams; what I want is for my own process to deal with its own stdin/stout in an async manner. Still, this is a nice 90% of the way there.

Comment: @DanS.:  Did you ever find a 100% solution?  I am now [trying to solve the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934444/asio-service-handler-for-stdin-keypress)

Answer (score 2):

I used the threads and platform specific code.  See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717572/c-nonblocking-io-on-linux/1280659#1280659).  I was able to put the OS-specific stuff in inputAvailable() (Linux uses select, Windows just returns true).  I could then use WaitForSingleObject() with a timeout on Windows to try to let the thread complete, then TerminateThread() to kill it.  Very ugly, but the team didn't want to use this bit of boost.

Comment: This only links to a non cross platform solution though (also includes a few stale links). Do you have the original implementation available somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, that was a past company, I no longer have that code. I believe the code for ``inputAvailable()`` is the Linux solution. Check out ``_kbit()`` as a starting place for Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to jwhitlock ... I ended up with a StdinDataIO class that wraps around the appropriate OS-specific implementation(*) so that the rest of my program can select() on the file descriptor StdinDataIO provides, remaining blissfully ignorant of Windows' limitations regarding stdin.  Have a look [here](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/dataio/StdinDataIO.h) and [here](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/dataio/StdinDataIO.cpp) if you like, the code is all open-source/BSD-licensed.

(*) the implementation is a simple pass-through for Linux/MacOSX, and in Windows it's a rather complex process of setting up a child thread to read from stdin and send the data it receives over a socket back to the main thread... not very elegant, but it works.