# reading input from the keyboard without pressing enter

Tags: c, input, delay, prompt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++: Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/c-c-capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pr)
>   [How do you do non-blocking console I/O on Linux in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717572/how-do-you-do-non-blocking-console-i-o-on-linux-in-c)

I am attempting to write a program in the C language which is in a constant loop but I need to be able to receive input from the keyboard at the start of each cycle or to continue on if there is no key being pressed.

getchar() and _getch() are insufficient as they both wait for the input. If anybody knows of a function similar to _getch but which doesn't wait for the input it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which system will your code run on?

Comment: post your code which u have tried..

Comment: C doesn't assume your keyboard device has this capability. If you know for a fact that yours does, you'll have to use some platform-specific function that shares this knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

There's no C-standard way to do what you want to do (capture keystrokes from the keyboard without the user hitting enter), you have to go platform specific. `<conio.h>` should have what you need on Windows, you'd need `curses` on Linux to get this. (I suspect `curses` would work on Mac as well, but don't quote me on that)

On Windows `kbhit()` doesn't wait for any input, it just returns if there is a key pressed at the very instant you make the test. If you need to know what the key was as well, then you can combine this with `getch()`

something like:

```
while(countdown++ <= 1000){  // give a second to hit something
    if(b=kbhit())            // if the user presses a key
        break;               // leave the loop early
    Sleep(1);                // else, sleep for 1 ms and try again
}
if (b != 0)          // if something was pressed
    printf("The key was %d\n", getch());
```