# Client-server chat room with select()

Tags: c, select, client-server, chat

I have an assignment that implements a Client-server chat room in C. I've got most of it down, but have got stuck on the client-side with regard to `select()`.

When a client connects to the server, he doesn't send anything unless the user actually inputs something to `stdin`. However, he should *still* receive all the messages that are either broadcast to all users or aimed specifically at him.

Ex.:

1. C1, C2, C3 are connected and talking
2. C4 connects, but says nothing. C1/2/3 still talking.
3. C1/2/3 see nothing with regard to C4 (except that he connected), but C4 sees all the messages that C1/2/3 have been sending since he connected.

So in essence, the client should block upon reading but still receive messages (quite contradictory!). The only way I can think of right now would be to make the client multi-threaded with one thread listening for receive, and the other for sending; or using `fork()`.

My question is the following: Is there an easier way to do the above with `select()`? Would select still do the trick if, say, I add `stdin` to my `write_fds` and both `stdin` the socket that is used to connect to the server to my `read_fds` (since I would need to read from both) and pass those to `select()`? Since TCP is full-duplex, there should be no issues when/if a read and a write happen at the same time, correct?

I guess essentially, what I want to implement is a simple telnet session for all of my clients. Any suggestions to that end would be quite welcome.

**EDIT**:

Something I neglected to mention: I am well aware that I can use `FD_ISSET` to both check if the server sent something and if the client sent something, but I see no way to make those behave the way I want it to. That is, I see no way to still receive something while "blocking" on send - perhaps adding a timer to the `select()` and periodically polling both the socket and stdin? I will attempt that and edit this post further, but any suggestions are quite welcome in the meantime.

Comment: It seems to me that you should take a look at telnet source code to see how it's done there, since you're aware that it can solve your problem. `select()` is certainly a reasonable option, as is multithreading.

Comment: You want to wait until *input* is available on either `stdin` or the socket.  You want to read from potentially both of them.

Comment: @mah I am doing that right now; I was merely curious whether `select() ` has the capability of doing what I described so I wasn't looking for something that's not there. Ian, good point - I will update my post to reflect that.

Comment: I seem to recall doing this assignment when I was in college.  I didn't need threads.  You should be able to make this work by simply `select`ing on `stdin` and your socket.  Waiting for `stdin` to be writable seems a bit silly.

Comment: @IanMcLaird My apologies for the late reply; How would I do that, though? To actually read from stdin I do have to use something like `fgets` - which blocks. These uses are contradictory, no?

Comment: See this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717572/how-do-you-do-non-blocking-console-i-o-on-linux-in-c