# Getting a single digit of user input

Tags: c, user-input, digit

I'm a begginer and this is my first post so go easy on me :)

Is there a better way of getting a single digit of user input, repeatedly?
The input should consist only in a single digit followed by the return key.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    int foo = getchar() - '0';
    if (foo == '\n' - '0' || getchar() != '\n')
        return 1;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Paulo Ribeiro

EDIT: After the loop I'm doing the following check.

```
switch (foo)
{
    case 1:
        //do something
    case 2:
        //do something
    case 3:
        //do something
    default:
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: There is no check if the input is digit.

Comment: You are looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717572/how-do-you-do-non-blocking-console-i-o-on-linux-in-c)?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY sorry, I'm doing the check afterwards with a switch case that accepts only a value of foo of 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: @neagoegab I don't think so

Comment: you can use scanf("%1d", &foo)...

Comment: @neagoegab that doesn't handle the 'single' digit part. If I input "123" it counts as three different inputs.

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read a whole line. Then, make sure you only have one digit in your input. You decide if you will accept the input or not by adding the appropriate code.

Comment: @jxh That was my first aproach but it took me 5 lines of code so it was more complicated.

Comment: For the fgets solution, you need only 3 bytes: one for the digit, one for the newline if it is present, and one for the null terminator. If the newline isn't present, it will be a null terminator if you read a single digit. Otherwise, you have more than just the one digit, if there is even a digit at all. The getchar solution works, but you must be sure that the next getchar call returns '\n' or EOF. Otherwise, you don't have just a single digit.

Comment: Use jxh's approach and make it into a function. Then you can use it everywhere and future improvements are seen by all callers. And five lines of code in a separate functzion will not make the client code, i.e where you use it, more complicated. Something like `n = getdigit()` will make it even more readable.

Comment: What I was aiming for was less code but I guess that doesn't necessarily mean more simplicity. I see now how the fgets solution is the simplest approach. Thank you for your help everyone.

Comment: Also, you can use `isdigit(foo)` to check `foo` is a digit (0 - 9)

Comment: @beachcabana, yup it will but you can use getchar to drop all remaining digits/characters including new line.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it goes in C :

```
scanf("%1d",&varname);
```