# Check keyboard input without stopping flow of loop

Tags: c++, input, keyboard

My question is can you check for keyboard input within a loop without halting the loop itself.

```
while(condition)
{
    if(keyboard input)
        action;

    more code;
    more code;
    more code;
    more code;
}
```

edit:
I'm using a linux machine.

Comment: Hard to do without operating system-specific functions. Best that you edit your question to specify which OS you are targeting.

Comment: good point, I'm using linux.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717572/how-do-you-do-non-blocking-console-i-o-on-linux-in-c

Comment: Thanks for that link, looks interesting, I didn't think to use ncurses.

Comment: The select statement approach in the second answer is also interesting. I've never tried that before.