# How to print what's on the command line C

Tags: c, command-line, printing

To build a chat, I have to send and receive messages. 
Currently, I am sending and receiving messages from the command line.
When I receive a message while I was typing one, the received message is printed and I can't see what was typed before. I use the `read()`command to catch the user input.

Here is an example:

Let's suppose I want to send the message `Hello World` and that I receive a message after typing `Hello Wor`.

This is what happens :

```
$ Enter your message : Hello Wor
$ Somebody: This is a message 
$ Enter your message :
```

But `Hello Wor` is still on the command line: if I press the Delete Key, I will see `Hello Wo`.
This is what I want :

```
$ Enter your message : Hello Wor
$ Somebody: This is a message 
$ Enter your message : Hello Wor
```

I would like to save what was typed before printing the received message and print it.

Comment: A text-mode chat application won't be using the minimal C `stdio` API - it would be using something like `curses` or `ncurses` to give it more control over what is rendered in the terminal window. The `stdio` isn't really meant for interactive input and output but meant for piping text-streams and batch processing.

Comment: where is the code? what is the problem?

Comment: @Dai Thank you for your answer, I have never heard of those API, problem solved !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using a terminal control API like `curses` or `ncurses`, you will need to change your program to work like-so:

1. Disable local echo, so your program handles every local keypress *before* it's rendered by the caret in the terminal.
2. Your local keypress handling code will need to be *asynchronous* so it doesn't block on `getchar` while waiting for the user to enter the next character of their message or `[Enter]`.

   - This is important so that your program can still run to collect and display messages received on the network end. While you could use a second thread for this it would mean two threads would be using `stdio` at the same time which is inadvisable, while you could use thread synchronization primitives to prevent this bug you're better-off using an asynchronous IO API instead.
   - Important note: "asynchronous" code does not mean "concurrent" nor does it imply the use of threading. In practice, it means the program's thread will return to a central dispatcher (cooperative yielding) instead of blocking on IO and the dispatcher will resume the function where it yielded when the IO operation completes (this is what the `await` keyword does in C# and JavaScript).
   - However, in C, [working with the asynchronous terminal/console API in Linux is a PITA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717572/how-do-you-do-non-blocking-console-i-o-on-linux-in-c) and you're better off using a library like `ncurses` which handles this for you.
3. When your program receives a message to display, you would clear the bottom line of the window (by overwriting it with whitespace or using VT100 `^[[2K`), write the received message, then re-write the user's incomplete entered input (if any) on a new line.
4. Repeat.